# Redshift - Extract value matching a condition in Array

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a Redshift table with the following column
[image: table]

How can I extract the value starting by cat_ from this column please (there is only one for each row and at different position in the array)?

I want to get those results:

> cat_incident
>
> cat_feature_missing
>
> cat_duplicated_request

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks! 
In the end I managed to do it with the following query:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(tags, charindex('cat_', tags), len(tags)), 0, charindex(',', SUBSTRING(tags, charindex('cat_', tags), len(tags)))) tags
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

There is **no easy way** to extract multiple values from within one column in SQL (or at least not in the SQL used by Redshift).

You could write a [User-Defined Function (UDF)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/user-defined-functions.html) that returns a string containing those values, separated by newlines. Whether this is acceptable depends on what you wish to do with the output (eg `JOIN` against it).

Another option is to **pre-process the data *before* it is loaded into Redshift**, to put this information in a separate *one-to-many* table, with each value in its own row. It would then be trivial to return this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using tally table (table with numbers). Check this link on information how to create this table: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Here is example how you would use it. In real life you should replace temporary #tally table with a permanent one.

```
--create sample table with data
create table #a (tags varchar(500));

insert into #a
select 'blah,cat_incident,mcr_close_ticket'
union
select 'blah-blah,cat_feature_missing,cat_duplicated_request';

--create tally table
create table #tally(n int);
insert into #tally
select 1
union select 2
union select 3
union select 4
union select 5
;

--get tags
select * from
(
select TRIM(SPLIT_PART(a.tags, ',', t.n)) AS single_tag
from #tally t
inner join #a a ON t.n <= REGEXP_COUNT(a.tags, ',') + 1 and n<1000
)
where single_tag like 'cat%'
;
```